# Can't Get Variable to Add Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables, conditional-statements

I have a variable++; in an if/else statement (it being in the else part). It's supposed to add 1 to a score of how many wrong guesses one has.
For some reason it never adds just one, it will also add numbers ranging from 3 to 7 whenever I submit a 'guess'. Can you guys tell me if I'm looping wrong or something? Please try to explain in detail.

**EDIT:** I realized part of the problem. The tries++; is actually looping once for each letter [var]choice didn't match or equal. For instance if I enter "a" for "apple" tries++; will loop four times because of the four other characters. So how do I get it to only loop only once instead of adding one for each missed character?

This is my code.

```
// JavaScript Document
var words = new Array("apple","orange","banana","lime","mango","lemon","avacado","pineapple","kiwi","plum","watermelon","peach");
var randomNum;
var word;
var tries = 0;

$('#guess').prop('disabled', true);

$(function(){
$('#start').click(function(){
    $('#guess').prop('disabled', false);
    word = "";
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)
    for (var i =0; i < words[randomNum].length; i++) {
        word += "*";
    }
    console.log(words[randomNum]);
    $('#word').html(word);
});

$('#guess').click(function guess(){
    var choice = $('#letter').val().toLowerCase();
    for (var i =0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (words[randomNum].charAt(i) == choice) {
            word = word.substr(0, i) + choice + word.substr(i + 1);
        } 
        if (words[randomNum].charAt(i) !== choice) {
            tries++;
        }
    }

    if (tries < 7) {
        $('#tries').html(tries)
    } else if (tries >= 7)
        $('#tries').html("YOU LOSE");

    $('#word').html(word);

    $('#' + choice).css("background-color", "red");
});

});
```

Comment: Which variable is the problem?

Comment: @CaseyRule: Probably the only one that's incremented anywhere, let alone in an if/else statement.

Comment: @Sarah: I can assure you that `tries` is _never_ subtracted from. Can you be clearer about your _actual_ precise observations instead of your [incorrect] conclusions? What did you see when you stepped through the code methodically in a debugger?

Comment: The `tries++` line is inside this: `for (var i =0; i < word.length; i++)` - also there's absolutely no reason to write an `else if` with the opposite condition to the `if` because that's the default behavior of just plain `else`.

Comment: Also note that because you declare `tries` in that "click" handler, and initialize it to zero, every "click" starts back over at zero.

Comment: @CaseyRule It is the **tries** variable.

Comment: @Pointy Are you saying that I may need to move the "tries++;" outside the click function? And I just rewrote the else if part as just an else statement.

Comment: @SarahDay You need to move `tries` variable out of the loop. I've provided an example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Got it working!

The issue is related to the `tries` variable, inside the `for` loop *(per letter)*. In order to see the odd behavior add a `console.log(tries);` in your code, inside the loop and you will see. At first time it will increase in `1` then the value will change completely *(I will suggest some debugging here to understand what's going on with more accuracy since I did this real quick)*. The solution is increasing the variable out of the `for` loop context to make it work *(I did this in the provided example from the bottom)*.

By the way, it seems that you are trying to implement a "Hangman" game and to be honest, when implementing those things you need to be really organized.

I fixed your issue, improved the code a lot and also considered other possible game scenarios like:

- Play Again
- Game Over
- Win
- Go Back

Please take a look. Just to know, HTML and CSS are just improvisations made for this example, some improvements are needed so just take them as a reference.

---

***Update:*** What you had put in the *EDIT* part from your post is correct.

---

***You can run this script at the bottom.***

```js
// Game variables
var GAME_WORDS = [ // List of words available when playing
        'apple', 
        'orange', 
        'banana', 
        'lime', 
        'mango', 
        'lemon', 
        'avacado', 
        'pineapple', 
        'kiwi', 
        'plum', 
        'watermelon', 
        'peach'
    ], 
    GAME_MASKED_WORD = '', // Stores the masked word to be discovered
    GAME_SELECTED_WORD = '', // Stores the readable word
    GAME_PLAYER_ATTEMPTS = 0, // Stores player attempts when failing
    GAME_RANDOM_NUMBER = 0, // Random number to pick a word
    GAME_MAX_ATTEMPTS = 7, // Max. player attempts before a game over
    GAME_UI_COMPONENTS = { // UI components declaration
        start: $('#start'), 
        reset: $('#reset'), 
        back: $('#back'), 
        guess: $('#guess'), 
        msg: $('#msg'), 
        word: $('#word'), 
        letter: $('#letter')
    }, 
    GAME_UI_SECTIONS = { // UI sections declaration
        menu: $('#menu'), 
        game: $('#game')
    };

$(function() {;
    var ui = GAME_UI_COMPONENTS;
    
    // Initialize game
    init();
    
    // Start button handler
    ui.start.on('click', function(e) {
        start();
    });

    // Guess button handler
    ui.guess.on('click', function(e) {
        guess();
    });
    
    // Play Again button handler
    ui.reset.on('click', function(e) {
        reset();
        start();
    });
    
    // Go Back button handler
    ui.back.on('click', function(e) {
        init();
    });
});

/**
 * Used to initialize the game for first time
 */
function init() {
    var sections = GAME_UI_SECTIONS;
    sections.menu.show();
    sections.game.hide();
    reset();
};

/**
 * Used to start the game
 */
function start() {
    var ui = GAME_UI_COMPONENTS, 
        sections = GAME_UI_SECTIONS, 
        words = GAME_WORDS;
    
    sections.menu.hide();
    sections.game.show();
    
    GAME_RANDOM_NUMBER = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < words[GAME_RANDOM_NUMBER].length; ++i) {
        GAME_MASKED_WORD += '*';
    }
    
    GAME_SELECTED_WORD = words[GAME_RANDOM_NUMBER];

    ui.word.html(GAME_MASKED_WORD);
    ui.letter.focus();
};

/**
 * Guess button handler
 */
function guess() {
    var ui = GAME_UI_COMPONENTS, 
        words = GAME_WORDS, 
        matches = false, 
        choice;

    // Clean messages each time player do a guess
    showMsg('');
    
    if (ui.letter && ui.letter.val()) {
        choice = $.trim(ui.letter.val().toLowerCase());
    }
    
    if (choice) {
        for (var i = 0; i < GAME_MASKED_WORD.length; ++i) {
            if (words[GAME_RANDOM_NUMBER].charAt(i) === choice) {
                GAME_MASKED_WORD = GAME_MASKED_WORD.substr(0, i) + choice + 
                    GAME_MASKED_WORD.substr(i + 1);
                matches = true;
            }
        }
        
        if (!matches) {
            ++GAME_PLAYER_ATTEMPTS;
        }
    } else {
        showMsg('Please type a letter.');
    }
    
    // Show attempts left if more than zero
    if (GAME_PLAYER_ATTEMPTS > 0) {
        showMsg('You have ' + 
                (GAME_MAX_ATTEMPTS - GAME_PLAYER_ATTEMPTS) + 
                ' attempt(s) left.');
    }
    
    // Check game status each time doing a guess
    if (isGameOver()) {
        lose();
    } else if (isGameWin()) {
        win();
    } else {
        ui.word.html(GAME_MASKED_WORD);
    }
    
    ui.letter.focus();
};

/**
 * Used to set all game variables from the scratch
 */
function reset() {
    var ui = GAME_UI_COMPONENTS;
    GAME_MASKED_WORD = '';
    GAME_PLAYER_ATTEMPTS = 0; 
    GAME_RANDOM_NUMBER = 0;
    showMsg('');
    ui.guess.show();
    ui.letter.val('');
    ui.word.html('');
};

/**
 * Handler when player lose the game
 */
function lose() {
    var ui = GAME_UI_COMPONENTS;
    showMsg('You Lose!');
    ui.word.html(GAME_SELECTED_WORD);
    ui.guess.hide();
};

/**
 * Handler when player win the game
 */
function win() {
    var ui = GAME_UI_COMPONENTS;
    showMsg('You Win!');
    ui.word.html(GAME_SELECTED_WORD);
    ui.guess.hide();
};

/**
 * Use to print UI messages for the player
 */
function showMsg(msg) {
    var ui = GAME_UI_COMPONENTS;
    ui.msg.html(msg);
};

/**
 * Check game status, if player is going to lose the game
 * @returns Boolean
 */
function isGameOver() {
    return (GAME_PLAYER_ATTEMPTS >= GAME_MAX_ATTEMPTS);
};

/**
 * Check game status, if player is going to win the game
 * @returns Boolean
 */
function isGameWin() {
    return (GAME_MASKED_WORD === GAME_SELECTED_WORD);
};
```

```css
.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
}

span#msg {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text {
    font-size: 3em;
}

input#letter {
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <span class="text">Hangman!</span>
        <br><br>
        <img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130207191137/scribblenauts/images/0/01/Hangman.png" height="200" width="120"/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" class="btn" id="start" value="Start Game"/>
    </div>
    <div id="game">
        <span id="msg"></span>
        <br><br>
        Letter: <input type="text" id="letter" value="" maxlength="1"/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" class="btn" id="guess" value="Guess"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn" id="reset" value="Play Again"/>
        <input type="button" class="btn" id="back" value="Go Back"/>
        <br><br>
        Word: <div id="word" class="text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Hope this helps.*

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

Modify `guess` click handler like this:

```
$('#guess').click(function guess(){
    var choice = $('#letter').val().toLowerCase(),
     found = false;
    for (var i =0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (words[randomNum].charAt(i) == choice) {
            word = word.substr(0, i) + choice + word.substr(i + 1);
            found = true
        }           
    }
    if(!found){
        tries++;
    }

    if (tries < 7) {
        $('#tries').html(tries)
    } else if (tries >= 7){
        $('#tries').html("YOU LOSE");
    }

    $('#word').html(word);

    $('#' + choice).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Also on `start` reset the `tries`:

```
$('#start').click(function(){
    $('#guess').prop('disabled', false);
    word = ""; tries = 0;
```